# Select folder option in Streamlit

Tags: python, tkinter, directory, streamlit

Any alternative for the below code

```
import streamlit as st
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

# Set up tkinter
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

# Make folder picker dialog appear on top of other windows
root.wm_attributes('-topmost', 1)

# Folder picker button
st.title('Folder Picker')
st.write('Please select a folder:')
clicked = st.button('Folder Picker')
if clicked:
    dirname = st.text_input('Selected folder:', filedialog.askdirectory(master=root))
```

I tried tkinter, but it only work if the application and the browser are running in the same computer.
So I require a alternative.

Comment: Hi, Rohan! Welcome! Can you read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to complete your question? Is important to tell us what an error and other important information is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.